# Добавление нескольких значений в одну запись MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Ребят нужен ваш совет, есть таблица заказов с записями. Так же есть таблица продуктов. В запись заказа нужно добавлять продукты (неограниченное количество). Как лучше это делать? До записывать данные в одну запись не хотеться, создавать большое количество столбцов под продукты тоже. Какие ещё есть варианты?

Comment: *создавать большое количество столбцов под продукты тоже* - вероятно Вы имеете ввиду *строк*, а не *столбцов*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создать связывающею таблицу:

- Номер заказа
- Продукт
- Кол-во

Праймери ключ - первые два поля
Запрос From из трех таблиц, в Where сравниваем номер заказа и продукт между таблицами. Получим все заказы и продукты, что можно отфильтровать если нужны не все а только определенного заказа.